# How to do unit testing rails for omniauth facebook on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, unit-testing, omniauth

I want to do unit testing for this method
here is the code :

```
 def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, sign_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if !Authentication.where(:uid => access_token['uid']).empty?
      authentication = Authentication.find_by_uid(access_token['uid'])
      if !authentication.user.nil?
        user = authentication.user
        return user
      else
        # in case for some reason the authentication has no user
        raise "Something went wrong"
      end
    else
      user = User.new
      user.authentications.build(:provider => access_token['provider'], :uid => access_token['uid'], :token => access_token['credentials']['token'])
      user.save(:validate=>false)
      return user
    end
    return false
  end
```

How to do it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on this site

http://ashleshawrites.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/testing-omniauth-creating-mock-data/

cheers :) Tq

Comment: Hah! That is a lot better than what I'm doing currently. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the example hash on the Omniauth-Facebook github page to isolate the test:
https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Scroll down to the "Auth Hash" to find the example.
Then it is simply a matter of testing like normal

Comment: But still error, undefined method 'extra' for #<Hash:0x596f6a0>. Any suggestion?  Tq

Comment: Change line #2 to    
**data = access_token['extra']['raw_info']**  
Then it should work

Comment: Then it is said that undefined method [ ] ... >_<

Comment: Are you sure the the access_token argument is a hash then?

Comment: Hmmmm, when I put request.env["omniauth.auth", it is not the same with the hash that you suggest for me on https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook ... Now I search for how to give the Hash in order to same with parameter on request.env["omniauth.auth" ... Tq